# Deleting specific row in table doesn't work, SQLite.Swift, Xcode 7

Tags: ios8, swift2, xcode7, sqlite.swift

I want to delete a row with the given value (`contactID`), which is also the primary key, in SQLite.Swift:

`let delRowCo = ContactTable.filter(ContactID == contactID)
 try db.run(delRowCo.delete())`

The given `contactID` surely exists, but it doesn't delete the row ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with some error handling. You'll catch if there are any errors.

```
do {
   if try db.run(delRowCo.delete()) > 0 {
       print("deleted")
   } else {
       print("row not found")
   }
} catch {
    print("delete failed: \(error)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this too.

```
let mytable = Table("ContactTable")
let delRowCo = mytable.filter(ContactID == 'contact_id')
try db.run(delRowCo.delete())
```